# How to rotate objects in OpenGL relative to local or global axes

Tags: c#, opengl, quaternions, rotational-matrices, sharpgl

I'm asking a question that has been asked a million times before, but I still haven't found a good answer after going through these and also resorting to other sites:

[How to rotate a graphic over global axes, and not to local axes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16246960/how-to-rotate-a-graphic-over-global-axes-and-not-to-local-axes)

[rotating objects in opengl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9559333/rotating-objects-in-opengl)

[How to rotate vertices exactly like with glRotatef() in OpenGL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10374063/how-to-rotate-vertices-exactly-like-with-glrotatef-in-opengl)

[Rotate object about 3 axes in OpenGL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3596675/rotate-object-about-3-axes-in-opengl)

[Rotate an object on its own axes in OpenGL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26293055/rotate-an-object-on-its-own-axes-in-opengl)

[Is it possible to rotate an object around its own axis and not around the base coordinate's axis?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7724840/is-it-possible-to-rotate-an-object-around-its-own-axis-and-not-around-the-base-c)

[OpenGL Rotation - Local vs Global Axes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9702867/opengl-rotation-local-vs-global-axes)

Task is relatively simple, I am making an sensor module with accelerometer and gyro onboard, and I need to display rotation.

I have a 3D model of the object in STL format, I've made an STL parser and I can visualise the object perfectly well.

When I try to rotate it I get all kinds of strange results.

I am using SharpGL (the Scene component).

I tried to write an "effect" that (for now) is controlled with 3 separate trackbars, but this will be the data from the sensors.

I wanted to do it as an effect because (in theory) I could have more objects in the scene and I only need to rotate a specific one (and also for educational purposes as I am relatively new to OpenGL).

I tried to rotate the object using quaternions, multiplying them and generating a rotation matrix, then applying `gl.MultMatrix(transformMatrix.AsColumnMajorArray)`.

I also tried `gl.Rotate(angleX, 1, 0, 0)` (and similar for Y and Z axes).

Depending on the order of quaternion multiplication or `gl.Rotate(...)` statements, I would get the object to rotate about the local axis (first), something weird (second), and the "world" third. For example, if I did it with quaternions `qX*qY*qZ` and got the rotation matrix from that, I would get (I think) the rotations about a local X, "arbitrary" Y, and the world Z axes.

The part I cannot understand is that when I apply `gl.Rotate(dx, 1, 0, 0)` (and others for Y and Z rotations) inside the trackbar's `Scroll` event, the entire scene rotates about the X, Y, and Z axes and in that order, and exactly as I expected the rotation to happen.

My only issue with this approach is that the entire scene rotates. So if I (hypothetically) wanted to draw a room around the object, the whole room would rotate too, which is not what I want.

I will post any code requested, but I feel there is too much and the aforementioned links have similar code to what I have.

At the end of the day, I want my object (`Polygon` in SharpGL terms) to rotate about its own axes (or about the "world" axes, but be consistent).

EDIT:

I've placed the project in my dropbox: https://goo.gl/1LzNhn

If someone wants to look at it, any help will be greatly appreciated.

In the `MainForm`, the TbRotXYZScroll function has trackbar code and the Rotation class is where the problem resides (or so I think).

Rotate X, Y, and Z by say 45 degrees in that order. All seems to work great. Now rotate X, Y, and Z further by another 30 or so degrees, try to visualise about which axis the rotation is happening as you rotate...
X seems to be always world and Z seems to be always local, while Y is something in between (changing the order of rotation changes this).

Going into TbRotXYZScroll function and changing method to 2 does what I want (except the rotation of the entire scene). Tried quaternions and they produce the exact same result, so ***I must be doing something wrong***...
Changing it to 1 produces similar result, but that is applying the rotation to the polygons alone (not what's being rendered as that includes local coordinate axes too).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> At the end of the day, I want my object (Polygon in SharpGL terms) to
>   rotate about its own axes (or about the "world" axes, but be
>   consistent).

I think [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7724840/is-it-possible-to-rotate-an-object-around-its-own-axis-and-not-around-the-base-c) you put in your question is somehow explaining the situation. In order to perform rotation around object axis:

**1.** Perform Translation/Rotation to your object and make the object axis overlap with one of base axis (x,y or z)

**2.** Perform your rotation

**3.** Revert your object back to its original position. (simply revert the translation/rotations at step1)

**Note:** While doing that, one thing you should consider is openGL apply transformations from the reverse order.

**Example :**

```
glRotatef(90,1,0,0); 
glTranslatef(-5,-10,5); 
drawMyObject();
```

In this case, opengl will first translate your object and then rotate. So while writing your transformations consider that. Here is [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26743207/rotating-around-a-point-different-from-origin/26743386#26743386) that may give you an idea.

Comment: Translation is not the issue as my object is located at the world origin (unless I grossly misunderstand something). Although that origin is not at the centre of the object, the obect lies in the first octant (where X, Y, and Z are all >0). Translating it so the geometric centre of the object lines up with the origin changes the point of rotation, but does not affect the original problem.

Comment: Thanks Cagkan, a careful read of your point #1 took me in the right direction.